# Terminal Ubuntu acessar um site todos os dias

Tags: web-service, linux, ubuntu, servidor, terminal

Eu estou trabalhando com uma WebService (SOAP + XML) que requer acesso todos os dias dias em um link, quero automatizar esse serviço no meu Servidor Ubuntu, pensei em utilizar o Lynx junto com CronTab para acessar o link e depois fechar, segue o código do CronTab:

```
0 6 * * * lynx https://site.com/WebService
1 6 * * * killall lynx
```

Assim, o acesso ocorre todos os dias, no mesmo horário e apos um minuto ele encerra tudo que existe do Lynx, o problema é que não funciona!

Ele acessa o link, mas é como se "não ativasse o XML" da pagina, logo, não funciona o WebService

O código da pagina foi desenvolvido em PHP e usando cURL para chamar/executar o XML.
Se acessar o link através de um navegador, funciona perfeitamente

Há algum jeito de resolver isso? Ou um outro método para automatizar esse acesso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentou usar CURL diretamente? Assim:

```
0 6 * * * curl --silent https://site.com/WebService
```

Uma duvida? Tem necessidade do PHP chamar o webservice? Quero dizer a não ser que precise salvar algo no site, como senhas ou dados baixados ou enviar dados do site, você poderia fazer o acesso ao WS diretamente pelo terminal, ou criar um script PHP na máquina mesmo, claro que eu estou supondo isto tudo, pois não sei como esta fazendo.

Mas se não tiver nenhum motivo em especifica para usar hospedar o script no site então poderia fazer algo como:

```
0 6 * * * php /home/meuusuario/scripts/webservice.php
```

Comment: Preciso sim do PHP! Pois é uma integração de sites, o PHP junto com o cURL criam um XML e envia ele, assim eu pego a informação do retorno, que é um número de sessão, falando que "estou conectado ao WebService", tenho que executar todos os dias pois essa sessão tem duração de 2 dias..
Posso postar qualquer parte do código se você deseja ver!
Por esse motivo não consigo hospedar no site ele, vou tentar o script que você fez e ver o resultado!

Comment: Tente primeiro só usar o `curl --silent`, talvez já funcione. @user70876

Comment: Acabei de realizar um teste aqui e já funcionou!! Já consegui acessar os serviços do WebService!

Já adicionei ao CronTab, amanhã eu verifico se já atualizou novamente!

Obrigado! Irei marcar sua resposta como correta!!

Comment: @user70876 você pode esperar até amanhã para marcar a resposta, primeiro faça os testes necessários. Até mais.